# How to display data in a ListView once you parse the XML with nested tag?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-listview

I have the XML file which is like this:

```
<activities>
<activity>
    <filename>http://www.someurl.com/documentSetting/members/0/701/66/videos/521/521.mp4</filename>
    <thumbnail>http://www.someurl.com/documentSetting/members/0/701/66/videos/521/521_120x90.jpg</thumbnail>
    <id>521</id>
    <is_private>0</is_private>
    <comments>
        <comment>
            <id>111</id>
            <body>Good video</body>
            <member_id>oo7</member_id>
            <profile_image>http://www.someurl.com/images/avatar/default_male_qlone.png</profile_image>
        </comment>
        <comment>
            <id>222</id>
            <body>nice video</body>
            <member_id>123</member_id>
            <profile_image>http://www.someurl.com/images/avatar/default_male_qlone.png</profile_image>
        </comment>
        <comment>
            <id>333</id>
            <body>gotcha!!!</body>
            <member_id>11</member_id>
            <profile_image>http://www.someurl.com/images/avatar/default_male_qlone.png</profile_image>
        </comment>
</activity>

<activity>
    <filename>http://www.someurl.com/documentSetting/members/0/701/66/videos/521/521.mp4</filename>
    <thumbnail>http://www.someurl.com/documentSetting/members/0/701/66/videos/521/521_120x90.jpg</thumbnail>
    <id>522</id>
    <is_private>0</is_private>
    <comments>
        <comment>
            <id>101</id>
            <body>aaa</body>
            <member_id>oo7</member_id>
            <profile_image>http://www.someurl.com/images/avatar/default_male_qlone.png</profile_image>
        </comment>
        <comment>
            <id>222</id>
            <body>bbb</body>
            <member_id>123</member_id>
            <profile_image>http://www.someurl.com/images/avatar/default_male_qlone.png</profile_image>
        </comment>
        <comment>
            <id>333</id>
            <body>ccc</body>
            <member_id>11</member_id>
            <profile_image>http://www.someurl.com/images/avatar/default_male_qlone.png</profile_image>
        </comment>
</activity>
```

Now i want to parse this XML file and Display it like this in ListView :::

Consider filename tag as Status ::

Status 1:

```
        Comment 1
        Comment 2   
        Comment 3 
        Comment 4
```

Status 2:

```
        Comment 1
        Comment 2   
        Comment 3
```

Suppose the first activity has 4 comment as a nested tag and second activity has the 3 comment in his comment tag.

How to do this?

Comment: Im pretty sure this has been answered before


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488915/how-data-can-be-parsing-in-xml-parsing-and-data-show-in-listview-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488915/how-data-can-be-parsing-in-xml-parsing-and-data-show-in-listview-in-android

Comment: I looked at this link.but how to display in listview as per my requirement as i mentioned in my question??? plz help me soon !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using  SAX Parser which is provided by Android.

Here's a good [example](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example)
how can u parse an XML file using SAX Parser method.

Comment: i am done with parsing but i am not able to display it accroding to my requirement in listview that's the problem.